# ¿Cómo se puede realizar un BAT que ejecute javac y después java?

Tags: java, windows

Estoy montando un banco de pruebas para testear código en Java, dentro de la consola de windows `cmd` ahora mismo tengo el siguiente

buildjava.bat

```
javac %1.java
java %1
```

Su uso es `buildjava nombrejavaapp` sin extensión .java

Me gustaría agregar verificación de si existe el archivo que se le pase al .bat en caso de error mostrar mensaje

Opcional seria que si hay algún error en java que lo muestre en rojo.

Comment: Webserveis, si deseas colocar la solución que has hecho al final puedes crear otra respuesta y colocarla ahí y aceptarla.

Comment: ¿Has pensado en usar Maven, Gradle, SBT, o cuando menos Ant?

Comment: @Omar si, pero no es para compilar digamos aplicaciones finales, simplemente es para testear código Java para integrar en apps de Android, es decir un "Test" prueba error

Comment: @Webserveis maven/gradle/sbt/ant no son para "compilar digamos aplicaciones finales", son herramientas que te ayudan en tu ciclo de desarrollo desde cómo estructurar el proyecto, compilación de código, pruebas y finalmente distribución. De esa manera tu código fuente y tu código de pruebas siempre están al día en el mismo proyecto, tu proyecto no se puede liberar si no pasa las pruebas. Deberías dar un mejor vistazo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Algo así...

```
if exist %1.java (
    javac %1.java
    if not exist %1.class (
      echo error de compilación
    ) else ( 
      java %1
    )
) else (
    echo el archivo no existe
)
```

Para usar rojo podrías hacerlo con `color 4` donde dice error de compilación, pero la consola quedara en rojo.

Comment: Ok, gracias modifico tu ejemplo poniendo lo de color 4 y el color 7 si todo está correcto.

Answer (score 1):

puedes probar con el siguiente código:

```
@echo off
if exist %~dp0\%1.java (
javac %~dp0/%1.java
java %~dp0/%1
) else (
COLOR 4 & echo "No se encuentra"
)
pause
```

`echo off` elimina la salida automática innecesaria. `%~dp0` te da el directorio actual. Le agregué un `pause` para que no se cierre tras imprimir y espere un caracter para cerrar.

Sé que color lo es lo ideal... pero estoy batallando un poco con la impresión con colores. Espero te sirva.

Comment: Gracias, utilizare ambos para crear el script final